# ¿Cómo asignar tipo a propiedad sobrescrita en clases en typescript?

Tags: typescript, poo

en este código conceptual de typescript están definidas las siguientes clases: `A` padre y `B` hija, existe la propiedad `config` que tiene un tipado de interfaz especifico en cada clase, pero genera un error, según el supervisor de Typescript,en la definición en la clase `B` por ser de tipo `IBConfig`, pero esta interfaz extiende de `IAConfig` con lo que no hay choque de propiedades, sin embargo persiste el error

ts versión : 5.1.6

```
interface IAConfig{
  color: string;
}
interface IBConfig extends IAConfig{
  borde: string
}
class A {
  protected config: IAConfig;
  constructor() {    
  }
}
class B extends A {
  protected config: IBConfig; //❌ts:2612 Error, no deja definir
  constructor() {  
    super();
    this.config = {
      color : "Azul",
      borde: "1px"
    };  
  }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo definirle ese tipo a la propiedad `config` de la clase `B`?.

Importante!: No se puede definir la clase `A` como abstracta porque se necesitan instancias de esa clase esto hace que tampoco se pueda definir como abstracta la propiedad `config`, y también pensar en escalabilidad (puede que exista la clase `C` que herede de `B`).

Comment: Cuando dices "genera un error", qué error exacto genera?

Comment: @Benito-B este es el error: 
Property 'config' will overwrite the base property in 'A'. If this is intentional, add an initializer. Otherwise, add a 'declare' modifier or remove the redundant declaration.
ese `declare` no es aconsejable para clases (según la documentación)

Comment: Y qué versión de TS dices que te genera ese error? Porque acabo de probar tu código ahora mismo y tiene 0 errores. Mientras extiendas la interface, no hay error

Comment: @Benito-B estoy usando vite, con el comando `tsc -v` me indica la 5.1.6 pero no se si vite me esta usando por debajo otra versión, ¿como puedo conocer que versión exactamente usa el proyecto, incluyendo en el archivo `package-lock.json`?

Comment: @Benito-B tienes toda la razón en el playground de typescript no aparece ese error, probándolo en la versión mas baja 3.3.3 y en la 5.1.6  y en ninguna aparece

Comment: Yep, probé múltiples versiones en el playground y no conseguí reproducirlo. No sé si es por algo de vite o qué. Pero si tienes problemas... una posibilidad sería quitar el `extends IAConfig` de tu interfaz `IBConfig` y tiparlo así en la clase: `protected config: IAConfig & IBConfig;`. De esa manera debería satisfacer perfectamente el tipado del padre y además darte seguridad en el tipado completo. Si pruebas esto en el playground de TS verás que es válido igualmente... lo que no sé es si ahí también te dará error o no

Comment: PS: Si eso te funciona siempre puedes crear los tipos intermedios si pretendes reutilizarlos, `type IABConfig = IAConfig & IBConfig;` funciona perfectamente igual.

Comment: @Benito-B Unión de tipos `IAConfig & IBConfig` tampoco funcionó, el problema en si es que para mi typescript asume que no puede definirse una propiedad `config` en la clase `B` porque ya esta definida en la clase `A` solo lo acepta si son exactamente del mismo tipo (extendido no cuenta).

Lo pase por chat-GPT para análisis de si existe algún error y también encuentra el error, dice que es por que no se puede redefinir la propiedad en la clase `B`

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de hacer varia, muchas, pruebas, se desecha este tipo de estructura, si bien ejecuta y aparentemente funciona (agregando `// @ts-ignore` para que no moleste), sin embargo no es aconsejable porque en mi implementación real me esta generando una sobreescritura peligrosa en la propiedad.

Lo recomendable es dejar la propiedad `config` definida en la clase padre así en la clase hija el tipado se pierda.

```
interface IAConfig{
  color: string;
}
interface IBConfig extends IAConfig{
  borde: string
}
class A {
  protected config: IAConfig;
  constructor() {    
  }
}
class B extends A {
  //protected config: IBConfig; //NO definir aquí
  constructor() {  
    super();
    this.config = <IBConfig>{ //agregar un incomodo cast
      color : "Azul",
      borde: "1px"
    };
    const otroUso = <IBConfig>this.config; //un incomodo cast cada vez que se use  
  }
  protected getConfig(){ //o usar este método
     return <IBConfig>this.config;
  }
}
```